# Error: Value of type 'String' has no member 'totalAnswered'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I am using CoreData for my project and I came into this error:

> Error: Value of type 'String' has no member 'totalAnswered'

Here is my circumstance:

I have a CoreData model with the entity "Scores" and the ff. attributes:

- datePlayed
- totalScore
- totalAnswered

I am using a table to show the data above.

Here is the problem part of my code for the Cell data:

```
if let date = score.datePlayed, let score = score.totalScore, let questions = score.totalAnswered {
```

I have no trouble saving into the entity "Scores" using the term "score" as illustrated in the code above. Also, I have no trouble showing the "score.datePlayed" and the "score.totalScore". However, the code "score.totalAnswered" is where I am having problems. It receives the error code above.

I have tried cleaning my project but the error still persist.

What should I do to show the data of "score.totalAnswered"?

EDIT:
I am using the code above to display the data using the ff. code:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "Date: \(date)\nScore: \(score)/\(questions)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the 2nd `let`. You create a new variable named `score` that hides the original variable named `score`. So the 3rd `let` is trying to access the wrong `score`.

The best solution is to use a different variable name on the 2nd `let`.

Comment: or use `let questions = self.score.totalAnswered`

Comment: thanks @rmaddy and Leo Dabus for answering my question!